# I can't seem to generate a migration for my rails app, how do I get past this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, simple-form, rails-migrations

```
    A:/Dev/Web/private_app/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameErr
    or)
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializ
    er'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrumen
    t'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Eng
    ine>'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializer
    s'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from e:/Dev/Rails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
```

Above is the error I'm receiving each time I try to generate a migration. How do I get past this or where would I start to debug?

Comment: It looks like you have partially installed [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). If you are using Simple Form in your project, try adding `gem 'simple_form'` to your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle install`. If you are not using Simple Form, try deleting the `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` file from your Rails project.

Comment: Hi Phil, I removed, then added simple form to the app and that fixed the issue. Thank you. Much obliged.

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have partially installed [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

If you are using Simple Form in your project, try adding `gem 'simple_form'` to your Gemfile and then run `bundle install`. If you are not using Simple Form, try deleting the `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` file from your Rails project.